# Autocomplete jquery in django

Tags: jquery, python, django

I use autocomplete in my site on Django, but i have a problem with output data. I have database (all city in Russia) and search field from this cities.

```
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
$(function() {
        $( "#automplete-2" ).autocomplete({
           source: '/asearch/',
           minLength:2,
           autoFocus:true
        });
     });

<input class="city_search" name="city" id = "automplete-2" placeholder="Введите город">
```

views.py:

```
def autocomplete(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    list = City.objects.filter(title__istartswith=request.GET.get('term', None)).values_list('title', flat=True)
    results = ''
    if list:
        for l in list:
            results = results + "%s\n" % (l)
        return HttpResponse(results)
    else:
        return HttpResponse('Не правильная раскладка', content_type="text/plain")
```

When I receive a response from the server, it is placed in one line. Several cities in one line. I need every city on a separate line. How to do it? Please, help)
http://promspros.ru/ the third field, but only Cyrillic.

```
<li class="ui-menu-item"><div id="ui-id-13" tabindex="-1" class="ui-menu-item-wrapper">Пятиверстица Пятигорская Пятигорский Пятигоры Пятидворка Пятидорожное Пятиизбянский Пятиморск
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you are trying to do because I don't understand Russian, but what I think the problem is is that you are making new lines in your python program using '\n', but html doesn't understand that as a new line. Try replacing it with `<br/>`. That might work.

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the source code for [this jQuery autocomplete example](https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/), you can see that the `source` argument is actually using a list.

Thus, your view should return a JSON list of your strings. (Currently, it's just returning one string). This can be achieved as follows:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse

def autocomplete(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        cities = City.objects.filter(title__istartswith=request.GET.get('term', None)).values_list('title', flat=True)
        if cities:
            return JsonResponse(cities)
        else:
            return HttpResponse('Не правильная раскладка', content_type="text/plain")
```

More information about the source parameter can be found here: http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#option-source

Comment: All the same in one line everything is displayed

Comment: is the view returning a JSON list?